# Calling a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I have a generic method. What is the difference between calling the method with specifying the type and calling without it.

When does it become mandatory to specify the type?

```
Write(1);
Write<int>(1);
Write<string>("test"); 
Write("test");

private static void Write<T>(T param)
{
    Console.WriteLine(param);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler will attempt to resolve the type argument at compile time. In cases where this is possible, it is done automatically without you have to specify an explicit type. In all other cases, when the compiler is unable to determine the type argument, the compiler will throw an error and you cannot compile your application.

In your example `Write(1)`, the argument `1` is of type `int`. So the compiler infers that `T` must be `int`, so the call is equivalent to  `Write<int>(1)`. Similarly with `Write("test")`, `"test"` is of type `string`, so the compiler will infer that `T` is `string`.

This generally works on the *compile time type* of the argument you pass to the function. So if you have a string with a compile time type of `object`, `T` would be `object`:

```
object arg = "foo";

Write(arg); // arg is object

// this is equivalent to this:
Write<object>(arg);
```

So although you are passing a string, its compile time type is `object` so that’s the only information, the compiler is able to use here.

In addition, you might want to specify the type argument explicitly whenever you want the compiler to use a different type than the compile time argument of what you’re passing to it. In the above example, you could use `Write<object>(1)` which would cause the integer `1` to be casted into `object`. However, in practice this usually defeats the purpose of generic methods and may have actual consequences even if you don’t need to access the actual parameter’s compile time type. For example, value types would be boxed when passed as `object` but generic methods allow you to keep them as value types—remember that a generic method definition (same applies to types) is kind of equivalent to specifying an overload with *every other valid* generic type argument value (so you usually have an infinite copy of methods).

Of course, the compiler’s type inference also works with multiple arguments:

```
void Write<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
{ … }

Write(1, "foo");
// is equivalent to
Write<int, string>(1, "foo");
```

However, when the compiler is not able to infer even one type argument, you will have to specify *all* of them in the call.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It's not mandatory in this situation because the parameter `param` is the generic (the compiler resolves it like that).

That means it's mandatory whenever the type argument is not supplied as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It becomes mandatory to specify the type when the compiler cannot infer it, or when you are not happy with what the compiler infers.

Answer (score 1):

There are no difference between

```
Write<string>("test");
Write("test");
```

But, there difference, when you specify not exactly type of parameter, but convertible, for example

```
Write<object>("test");
Write("test");
```

Just try to print type parameter and will see difference

```
private static void Write<T>(T param)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    Console.WriteLine(param);
}
```